# Optimization of memory allocation's speed while copying buffers in java

Tags: java, performance, memory

I have the following problem, I am designing an application that will send messages to a remote peer.

Upon calling **send** (buffer b), I would like the class that implements **send** to use a copy of buffer b instead of b instance. b's copy will have to be locked to reuse until the message is actually sent. Basically I would like to avoid calling new each time a send is called.

I was wondering if there was any optimal way to tackle this issue, for example using an automatic-sizable memory pool (I would like to avoid writing a customized solution for this problem if possible).

Comment: I'd suggest that initially you just normally allocate objects (maybe hidden behind an interface), and only start optimizing by using pools, etc, once you have conclusive evidence that Java's default allocation performs badly. That also gives a baseline that allows you to check if your solution is actually faster.

Comment: Copying buffers gives terrible performance.  Try to not copy, but maintain a pool of buffers which are in use/not in use.  New buffers are allocated from the existing pool or allocated new.  I believe Java's buffer strategy works this way under the hood so just allocating new buffers and allowing old ones to be GC'ed might give this type of performance.